# What is the diagram of the roto-inversion of $\bar 6$?

Tags: symmetry, crystallography

Using the standard way of representation:

[image]

Here we have a rotation followed by an inversion (technically called 'rotational inversion'). So as to represent it, what I have done is:

1) Both rotation and inversion occur for the first time. The circle changes of plane:

[image]

2) Both rotation and inversion occur for the second time. The circle changes of plane again:

[image]

My issue is that I am not convinced of this, because in theory there is rotation **followed** by an inversion and they do not happen simultaneously. So if this is wrong, what is the correct representation and why?

Diagram for $\bar 3$

[image]

Diagram for $\bar 6$

[image]

METHOD:

[image]

[image]

[image]

NOTE: I have used comma to stress there was an inversion

Thank you

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87422/discussion-on-question-by-jd-pm-what-is-the-diagram-of-the-roto-inversion-of-b).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The image below gives some example of different rotation inversion operations. For the $\bar 6$ operation rotate by 60 degrees (black dot to open circle in the direction towards 3) then invert through the centre of coordinates to the opposite side. Inversion changes a point at (x, y, z) to (-x, -y, -z) thus, in the diagram point 1 becomes point 2 after the whole operation, then 2 becomes 3 and so on. Two $\bar 6$ operations moves 1 to 3 and 6 operations places it back where it started.

[image: rotation inversion]

[The image is from 'Crystallography, An introduction ' by W. Borchardt-Ott, 3rd ed publ Springer.]